# How do i get the quotation mark on ipad pro with logitech keyboard?

Tags: ipad, keyboard

When i want to type ", i get «» instead. And it shoes the quotation mark on the keyboard being on number 2, but it´s the double arrow instead. How do i fix this? Nordic layout btw.

Comment: What app? Do you see this in Mail, Notes, Pages, and Message?

Comment: “Nordic” is too vague. Is it danish or Norwegian?  Or something else?  What is your setting for “hardware keyboard”, st right edge?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings/General/Keyboard and turn Smart Punctuation OFF.